# Rebuild openshift cartridge without deleting app

Tags: openshift

I have production golang app running on openshift using this cartridge (https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart) with a mysql database. The cartridge has had some updates which I would like to pull into my app.

Is it possible to reploy the base cartridge into my gears without deleting the whole application?

Answer (score 0):

If your repository contains `.openshift/markers/hot_deploy`, when you perform a `git push` OpenShift will not rebuild the application and perform a hot deployment instead.

See the [Hot Deploying Applications](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-OpenShift-User_Guide-Hot_Deploying_Applications.html) section of the user guide, as well as [this blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/new-openshift-release-aug-28-2012-hot-deployments-sftp-rest-api-and-more) (which somehow contains more specific details about where the marker file goes)